# How to set ng-pattern for numbers in HTML/Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I've few doubts/huddles for my page

1). I've a input control. It should only allow user to enter between 1 to 5. If user tries to enter maximum of 5, error should be thrown.
will ng-pattern="/^[1-5]*$/" correct?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="MovieRating" class="form-control" name="MovRate" ng-pattern="/^[1-5]*$/" required />
<span ng-show="adduserform.MovClafictn.$error.pattern" class="spnmsg">Rating should be 1 to 5</span>
```

2)Have one more input control which should be entered 4 digits only. Less than that/More of it should trigger validation. (Actually this control for entering year value)

Comment: Plus how can i validate user has entered valid year.....For ex:user enters 5555, i should throw error.....!!

Comment: use `ng-pattern= /19[789]\d|20[01]\d/g` for allowing user to enter only 1979 to 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ng-pattern="/^\d{5}$/"
```

This will allow user to enter only 5 digit number.

You can also make use of `ng-maxlength` as well for specifying the length and `input type="number"` for allowing only numbers.

Similarly if you want to allow only between 1 to 5, then set `min="1"` `max="5"` in your `input type="number"`

Regarding valid year:

```
ng-pattern = "/19[789]\d|20[01]\d/g"
```

This will allow from `1979` to to `2019`

Else even simple `ng-pattern = "^(19|20)\d{2}$"` will match from `1900` to `2099`

Comment: Am i missing something....
`<input type="text" ng-model="MovDate" class="form-control" name="MovDate" ng-pattern="^(19|20)\d{2}$" required  />
                        </div>
                            <span ng-show="adduserform.MovDate.$error.required" class="spnmsg">Field must not be empty</span>
                            <span ng-show="adduserform.MovDate.$error.pattern" class="spnmsg">Should be valid Year</span>

                        </span>`
Above code not triggering validation

Comment: try this with previous condition : `ng-pattern = "/^(19|20)\d{2}$/g"` we missed `//`